# Is it more efficient to farm more during spring and rely on stockpiles during winter?

Tags: kittens-game

I think this pretty much boils down to:
Does the season bonus/penalty apply to **both Catnip fields AND farmers** or **ONLY Catnip fields**?

I've been assigning my kittens to farming during spring and other jobs during winter, thinking that it's more efficient that way, but I was wondering if this is really the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general formula for the different resources is [[1]](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Resources):

```
perTick = (building output * season modifier + job output * upgrades * happiness) * building % effects + automatic effects - consumption * consumption % effects
```

The relevant part is the first:

```
perTick = (building output * season modifier + job output * extra....)
```

You see that the season modifier is **only relevant for the catnip fields** or any other buildings you later can build (I don't know, but I can't see why not). So it is **not** more effective to put farmers to work in the spring, as the season has no influence on the farmers.

This is how I handle my catnip successfully right now (32 kittens):

> So 32 kittens, 3 are farmers.  76 catnip fields, 32 pastures and 27 aquaducts. Also 11 unicorn pastures. Happiness is 61%, 71% or 81%, depending on the special goods. Also the mineral and iron hoes upgrade (50% and 30% more effective). But the most important part is just 3 kittens as farmer. The skills are 1x proficient and 2x competent. This all results in a overall positive catnip production, so I don't have to change farmers in a bad season. Good luck!

Comment: I was in the middle of writing the answer myself when you posted it, so I didn't see it. I couldn't wait any longer so I checked for myself :) Should I leave it there?

Comment: Sure, you can leave it there. You took a different approach (I read the wiki, you the game files)

Answer (score 4):

The season bonus **doesn't apply** to farmers, so there's no reason to switch jobs unless your kittens are in danger of starving or you need the resources.

It turns out it's not that difficult to check: increase or decrease the number of farmers during spring or winter and you will notice that the catnip production/second will be modified by 5 (barring other modifiers such as happiness).

Also, to be sure, I checked game.js and here's what I found:

```
    //SEASON MODIFIERS
    ...
    perTick = perTick * weatherMod;
    ...

    //VILLAGE JOB PRODUCTION
    ...
    perTick += resProduction;
```

so the season modifiers (including *warm/cold*) are applied before village job bonuses.

Note that this applies to the current version (v0.9.6.8)